# tkinterのプルダウンリストのフォントサイズが変更できない

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

tkinterを使ったGUIアプリを作成しております。
その中でコンボボックスを使っていますが、
プルダウンリストのフォントサイズが変更できません。

手元の環境では以下のコードで事象が発生します。

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

def study_time():
    study_root = tk.Tk()
    study_root.title("勉強時間登録")
    study_root.geometry("600x200")
    study_frame = tk.Frame(study_root,bd=2,relief="ridge")
    study_frame.pack(fill="x")
    label1 = tk.Label(study_root,text="【勉強時間登録】",font=("",20),height=2)
    label1.pack(fill="x")
    ###コンボボックスのリストの文字サイズ指定###
    font = Font("", size=22)
    study_root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox.Font", font)
    ###コンボボックスのリストの文字サイズ指定###
    study_frame = tk.Frame(study_root,pady=15)
    study_frame.pack()
    study_label = tk.Label(study_frame,font=("",18),text="勉強時間")
    study_label.pack(side="left")
    study_time = ttk.Combobox(study_frame,font=("",22),width=13)
    study_time["values"] = ("0:00","0:30","1:00","1:30","2:00","2:30","3:00")
    study_time.pack(side="left",padx=10)
    study_time.config(state='readonly')

    study_root.mainloop()
    
#####  GUI  #####
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x400")
root.title("study_time")
push_button1 = tk.Button(root,text = 'study_time', font=("MSゴシック",18), \
 fg='#000000', width= 15, height = 2,command=study_time)
push_button1.place(x = 300, y = 250)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 手元の環境では、`study_time()`関数を呼び出した場合、正しくフォントサイズの変更が反映されました。周辺の処理で`font`変数の値が変わっていないかをご確認ください。それでも原因が不明な場合はimport文や関数の呼び出し箇所を含む[再現可能な短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)をご提示いただくと、正確な回答をもらえる可能性が上がります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tkinter.font.Font`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.font.html)を変数として作成する時に、引数の`root`を指定しないと親コントロールがない状態となります。
そのため、**関数終了時に不要なローカル変数として破棄**されてしまいます。

文字サイズ指定のコードを下記のように書き換えて親コントロールを指定することでフォントサイズが維持されます。

```
    ###コンボボックスのリストの文字サイズ指定###
    # font = Font("", size=22) # 修正前
    font = Font(root=study_root, size=22) # 修正後
```

参考情報： [Python3 Tkinter クラス化で分からない部分がある](https://teratail.com/questions/248042)